# Macmini _ 16 GB and Vmware Fusion

Tags: vmware-fusion

Is 16 GB the max amount of ram for a macmini dualcore core i5?
Would it be enough to run a Exchange 2013 virtual lab using VMWARE FUSION?

I don't want to spend money right now on a virtual lab box, unless I have to..

Would adding ssd help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There's not much you can do to get more memory. You need to make sure you're not hitting the swap file in OSX though, as it will slow down the system. Run `purge` now and then when you get out of memory.

Yes. Your i5 is dual core, but it has 4 virtual processors, so you're good with parallelism, if you were concerned about that.

Yes. SSD always helps overall system performance.

We're done here. :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dual code". A i5 would only have 2 virtual processors to match the dual core nature of the processor.

Comment: Dual core, not code. I corrected that... i5-3210M Processor has 2 cores, 4 virtual CPUs http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/